# Java Spring SQL how to combine/join 3 tables into one

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, hibernate

I have 3 tables that I want to combine/join into one, I have tried different methods like join, left/right join but somehow i lose myself in the amount of statements i write so i cant get it to work properly.

I want to map the **name** in *measurement* to **measurement_id** in *measurement_data_points* and then map **data_points_id** in *measurement_data_points* to **id** in *measurement_point*

I have included a made-up result that i would like at the bottom to give a clear understanding.

**My Tables:**

```
+-------------------------+
| Tables_in_db_datapoints |
+-------------------------+
| measurement             |
| measurement_data_points |
| measurement_point       |
+-------------------------+
```

**measurement table**

```
mysql> select * from measurement;
+----+----------------------+
| id | name                 |
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | identifiedNeed       |
|  2 | identifiedBackground |
|  3 | identifiedGoal       |
+----+----------------------+
```

**measurement_data_points table**

```
mysql> select * from measurement_data_points;
+----------------+----------------+
| measurement_id | data_points_id |  
+----------------+----------------+
|              1 |              1 | 
|              1 |              2 | 
|              1 |              3 | 
|              1 |              4 | 
|              2 |              5 |    
|              2 |              6 | 
|              2 |              7 | 
|              2 |              8 | 
|              3 |              9 | 
|              3 |             10 | 
|              3 |             11 | 
|              3 |             12 | 
+----------------+----------------+
```

**measurement_point table**

```
+----+------------+-----+----------+--------+
| id | date       | f1  | precison | recall |
+----+------------+-----+----------+--------+
|  1 | 2017-11-19 | 0.3 |      0.5 |    0.2 |
|  2 | 2017-11-12 | 0.7 |      0.4 |   0.15 |
|  3 | 2017-11-15 | 0.5 |      0.3 |    0.1 |
|  4 | 2017-11-18 | 0.6 |      0.2 |   0.05 |
|  5 | 2017-11-19 | 0.2 |      0.4 |    0.2 |
|  6 | 2017-11-12 | 0.4 |      0.3 |   0.15 |
|  7 | 2017-11-15 | 0.5 |      0.2 |    0.1 |
|  8 | 2017-11-18 | 0.6 |      0.1 |   0.05 |
|  9 | 2017-11-19 | 0.1 |      0.4 |    0.2 |
| 10 | 2017-11-12 | 0.4 |      0.3 |   0.15 |
| 11 | 2017-11-15 | 0.3 |      0.2 |    0.1 |
| 12 | 2017-11-18 | 0.2 |      0.1 |   0.05 |
+----+------------+-----+----------+--------+
```

**I want the result to mainly be like this:**

```
+-----------------------+----------------+------------+-----+----------+        
| measurement_id        | data_points_id |  date      | f1  | precison | recall |
+-----------------------+----------------+------------+-----+----------+ 
| identifiedNeed        |              1 | 2017-11-19 | 0.3 |      0.5 |    0.2 |
| identifiedNeed        |              2 | 2017-11-12 | 0.7 |      0.4 |   0.15 |
| identifiedNeed        |              3 | 2017-11-15 | 0.5 |      0.3 |    0.1 
| identifiedNeed        |              4 | 2017-11-18 | 0.6 |      0.2 |   0.05 |
| identifiedBackground  |              5 | 2017-11-19 | 0.2 |      0.4 |    0.2 |
| identifiedBackground  |              6 | 2017-11-12 | 0.4 |      0.3 |   0.15 |
| identifiedBackground  |              7 | 2017-11-15 | 0.5 |      0.2 |    0.1 |
| identifiedBackground  |              8 | 2017-11-18 | 0.6 |      0.1 |   0.05 |
| identifiedGoal        |              9 | 2017-11-19 | 0.1 |      0.4 |    0.2 |
| identifiedGoal        |             10 | 2017-11-12 | 0.4 |      0.3 |   0.15 |
| identifiedGoal        |             11 | 2017-11-15 | 0.3 |      0.2 |    0.1 |
| identifiedGoal        |             12 | 2017-11-18 | 0.2 |      0.1 |   0.05 |
+-----------------------+----------------+------------+-----+----------+
```

**If that doesnt work then this works as well**

```
+----------------+----------------+------------+-----+----------+--------+
| measurement_id | data_points_id | date       | f1  | precison | recall |
+----------------+----------------+------------+-----+----------+--------+
|              1 |              1 | 2017-11-19 | 0.3 |      0.5 |    0.2 |
|              1 |              2 | 2017-11-12 | 0.7 |      0.4 |   0.15 |
|              1 |              3 | 2017-11-15 | 0.5 |      0.3 |    0.1 |
|              1 |              4 | 2017-11-18 | 0.6 |      0.2 |   0.05 |
|              2 |              5 | 2017-11-19 | 0.2 |      0.4 |    0.2 |
|              2 |              6 | 2017-11-12 | 0.4 |      0.3 |   0.15 |
|              2 |              7 | 2017-11-15 | 0.5 |      0.2 |    0.1 |
|              2 |              8 | 2017-11-18 | 0.6 |      0.1 |   0.05 |
|              3 |              9 | 2017-11-19 | 0.1 |      0.4 |    0.2 |
|              3 |             10 | 2017-11-12 | 0.4 |      0.3 |   0.15 |
|              3 |             11 | 2017-11-15 | 0.3 |      0.2 |    0.1 |
|              3 |             12 | 2017-11-18 | 0.2 |      0.1 |   0.05 |
+----------------+----------------+------------+-----+----------+--------+
```

Comment: had You any question about Hibernate, Java and Spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you request is quite simple.  It uses the "main" table (measurement) joined with the other two.
A "join" is a way to link two tables, using one or more fields.
In your case, for example, you can join measurement with measurement_data_points using the field measurement_id using following sintax (inside a SELECT command):

```
...
FROM measurement A
LEFT JOIN measurement_data_points B ON A.measurement_id= B.measurement_id
```

Once joined, you can use in your SELECT every fields of the two tables.  Eg.

```
...
SELECT  measurement.name
    , measurement_data_points.data_points_id
...
```

Putting all together, it should be simply:

```
 SELECT measurement.measurement_id
    , measurement_data_points.data_points_id
    , measurement_point.date
    , measurement_point.f1
    , measurement_point.precison
    , measurement_point.recall
FROM measurement 
LEFT JOIN measurement_data_points  ON measurement.measurement_id= measurement_data_points.measurement_id
LEFT JOIN measurement_point ON measurement_data_points.data_points_id = measurement_point.id ;
```

**Query with measurement name instead of measurement id:**

```
SELECT measurement.name
    , measurement_data_points.data_points_id
    , measurement_point.date
    , measurement_point.f1
    , measurement_point.precison
    , measurement_point.recall
FROM measurement 
LEFT JOIN measurement_data_points  ON measurement.measurement_id= measurement_data_points.measurement_id
LEFT JOIN measurement_point ON measurement_data_points.data_points_id = measurement_point.id ;
```

Tip: all these are very simple queries and if you just use a few of your time to read something about SQL SELECT  and SQL JOIN (look on Internet) you will be capable to make queries like this by yourself and with satisfatcion.

Comment: what is A B C iam getting confused are you refering to A as first table, B second table, C third table?

Comment: It's just an alternative name (so called alias) for the tables, you can change with every name as you like...  Or just use only the original name of the table.  See updated answer... I thought you know a bit of SQL language...

Comment: It worked great thank you! But is there a way to make it appear as the main result i wanted? right now i get the second result. I need the ids 1 1 1 1 to turn to identifiedNeed and 2 2 2 2 to turn to identifiendBackground etc

Comment: You sir are a genius in the world of databases! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select M.Name, data_points_id, date, f1 ,precision , recall 
from measurement M
Inner join measurement_data_points md on m.id=md.measurement_id
inner join measurement_point mp on mp.id=md.data_points_id
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT a.name AS measurement_id,
       b.data_points_id,
       c.date,
       c.f1,
       c.precision,
       c.recall
FROM measurement a,
     measurement_data_points b,
     measurement_point c
WHERE a.id = b.measurement_id
  AND b.measurement_id = c.measurement_id;

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.